# Sort values in stacked bar highcharts not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts

I tried to sort values in stacked bar base on this question [Sort the series data for every X-Axis in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34565347/4964569)

But after sorting, the data in series seem wrong.

The code for sorting

```
seriesData.forEach(function (name) {
              if (name.data != undefined) {
                name.data.sort(function (a, b) {

                  if (a < b) {
                    return -1;
                  } else if (a > b) {
                    return 1;
                  }
                  return 0;
                });
              }
            });
```

Here is full my source code

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/hdy2frkv/9/

```js
var seriesData = [{
    "name": "(Component)",
    "data": [2039521123, 0, 0, 4046613348, 0, 544280301, 3865715691, 0],
    "display": 2,
    "stack": "Forecast",
    "showInLegend": false,
    "pointPadding": 0,
    "pointPlacement": 0
  }, {
    "name": "(Substrate)",
    "data": [1848232605, 1109333700, 0, 0, 1478070275, 0, 0, 0],
    "display": 2,
    "stack": "Forecast",
    "showInLegend": false,
    "pointPadding": 0,
    "pointPlacement": 0
  }, {
    "name": "(Module)",
    "data": [0, 532822345, 452625462, 0, 0, 207607714, 0, 103089669],
    "display": 2,
    "stack": "Forecast",
    "showInLegend": false,
    "pointPadding": 0,
    "pointPlacement": 0
  }, {
    "name": "(Support)",
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 537829903, 0, 0],
    "display": 1,
    "stack": "Forecast",
    "showInLegend": false,
    "pointPadding": 0,
    "pointPlacement": 0
  }, {
    "name": "(Component)",
    "data": [11118985500, 0, 4732915644, 14216361483, 0, 3423432732, 3216931478, 0],
    "display": 1,
    "stack": "Real",
    "showInLegend": false
  }, {
    "name": "(Substrate)",
    "data": [8495153800, 3191092821, 0, 0, 13153490000, 0, 0, 0],
    "display": 3,
    "stack": "Real",
    "showInLegend": false
  }, {
    "name": "(Module)",
    "data": [0, 13925175787, 9837488553, 0, 0, 3705001758, 0, 338212038],
    "display": 1,
    "stack": "Real",
    "showInLegend": false
  }, {
    "name": "(Support)",
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4845038686, 0, 0],
    "display": 1,
    "stack": "Real",
    "showInLegend": false
  }, {
    "name": "Forecast",
    "color": "#fe7c7c",
    "events": {}
  }, {
    "name": "Real",
    "color": "#43d487",
    "events": {}
  }];
  
  
  var option = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textOutline: false,
        color: ( // theme
          Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
          Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
        ) || 'gray'
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'center',
    x: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    y: 5,

    backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      pointPadding: 0.05,
      maxpointWidth: 35,
      //groupPadding:0.1,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: {
      maxpointWidth: 35,
      groupPadding: 0.36,
      //stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.y === this.point.stackTotal || this.y == 0) {
            return ''
          }
          return this.series.name;
        },
        enabled: true,
        //allowOverlap: true,
        //align: 'right',
        color: '#444',
        textOutline: false,
        shadow: false,
        //x:-50,
        style: {
          fontSize: "8px",
          textShadow: "0px"
        }
      },
      //pointPadding: 0.1,
      pointWidth: 50,
      groupPadding: 0.2,
      stacking: 'normal',
      //colorByPoint: true,
      //showInLegend: false
    }
  },
  series: []
}

 seriesData.forEach(function (name) {
          if (name.data != undefined) {
            name.data.sort(function (a, b) {
              
              if (a < b) {
                return -1;
              } else if (a > b) {
                return 1;
              }
              return 0;
            });
          }
        });
        
option.series = seriesData;

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', option);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Updated:

When i tried Sebastian sample but chart display incorrect

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to achieve - that's how it looks like your chart without sorting - a little bit messy - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6os7qL9a/ and is that the wanted output - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gax46opv/?

Comment: I want to display value for each stack display from the bigger on top, smaller at bottom, but after sort, data seem change

Comment: I also follow this solution but not work in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651995/highcharts-sort-stacked-bar

Comment: Please take a look at this simplified demo - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fc81b2nL/ For me each stack has been sorted - bigger on top, smaller at bottom. Is it a wanted result?

Comment: your demo is not my requirement, I explain in attach image

Comment: Thank you for the image, it explains a lot. I think that you want to achieve something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z45r2aeq/ - I just changed the order of the rendered series manually. I am afraid that this requirement is impossible to achieve using regular API options - it is against the current `stacking` logic. Let's consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gzs47ey/ As you can see Highcharts render each `stacking level` in order to rendered series - in this case, it is impossible to achieve it without changing the data.

Comment: can you help me the algorithm to change order of series? I am not clear the rule to change order yet

Comment: Implementing this type of algorithm depends on the output of your data set. If your data will be like `data1: [1,2,3,4,5] and data2: [2,3,4,5,6]` - there is no problem because for each point from `data1` the `data2` has a higher value, but if the data will be like: `data: [2, 10, 4] and data2: [4, 2, 10]` it is a problem because the first point is higher in the data2, the second one in the data2 etc... Your requirement needs to break the current logic of creating the stack columns

Comment: After digging deeper into your requirement I can suggest four solutions. 1. Changing your data and implement the algorithm which will count the order of rendering the series. 2. You can try to customize the logic responsible for creating the `stack columns` by yourself https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/Stacking.js#L309 3. Or you can report the idea about this feature on Highcharts userVoice channel - https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api 4. You can contact the https://www.blacklabel.pl/ - specialist in customization Highcharts